# WordPress posts in phpBB topics

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget, phpbb, phpbb3

I like to know if there is a way to create topics on specific Forums when I save posts on WordPress side. Is there any tutorial available?

More specific. I like to allow my plugin users to combine a WordPress category to a phpBB forum, and when I create a new post in the WordPress, automaticly to create a topic in the phpBB side in the corresponding forum.

ie: Post that are posted on Tech News category, automaticly to be posted on Technology news forum on the phpBB side.

Any solution for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BBPress is supposed to do exactly this.
http://bbpress.org/

If you want to develop your own Wordpress plugin, take a look at phpBB's submit_post function:
http://wiki.phpbb.com/Using_phpBB3%27s_Basic_Functions#1.4.7._Inserting_Posts_and_Private_Mess
http://wiki.phpbb.com/Function.submit_post

and Wordpress' publish_post function, located in wp-includes/post.php
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to switch to bbPress, you can use [WP-United](http://www.wp-united.com). It only allows you to select one forum to cross-post to at the moment, but it would be an easy change to cross-post based on category: I'm considering adding that for v0.9.2